# Calculate number of turtles in time Netlogo

Tags: time, netlogo, agent, ticker

Hello i am trying to write a code in which i can know the difference in the composition of turtles every time a new tick has passed. Explicitly, i need to count the turtles let say of color blue in a population of turtles with different colors in the first time or tick 1, and then count again in the next time or tick 2 and calculate the difference of turtles with color blue between the time step and need to use that value for other purpose so what kind of primitive can i use?

```
    let current-population-count map [count turtles with [color = ?]] colors 
    let new-population-count (map[?1 * (savage ?2)] current-population-count colors)
    set new-population-count map [num-turtles * ? / sum new-population-count] new-population-count
```

Try to using this code but this not work for my purposes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need one timestep previous then the easiest is to store it in a global variable. If you need to keep a full history over all timesteps, you will need to use a list. This is the one timestep code and just one colour (not tested).

```
globals [lastblue]

to go
  ...
  let thisblue count turtles with [color = blue]
  if ticks > 1 [do whatever you want with thisblue and lastblue]
  set lastblue thisblue
  tick
end
```